# Looping over pointers

Tags: go

Please consider snippet https://play.golang.org/p/GnhA1Tgw4sz, it is a simplified version of a problem that I ran into. My original issue was trying to send UDP messages to destinations in an array, and I noticed trouble with even distribution.

Also, the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var (
    dests = [...]string{"word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7", "word8"}
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello!")
    fmt.Println("dests", dests)

    for _, dest := range dests {
        fmt.Println("dest is", dest)

        go func(dest_ptr *string) {
            fmt.Println("Trying", *dest_ptr, dest_ptr)
        }(&dest)

    }

    time.Sleep(200 * time.Second)
}
```

When I run,

```
Trying word8 0x40c140
Trying word8 0x40c140
Trying word8 0x40c140
Trying word8 0x40c140
Trying word8 0x40c140
Trying word8 0x40c140
Trying word8 0x40c140
Trying word8 0x40c140
```

Notice here that I am hitting `word8` all the time, likely since the `&dest` gets overwritten. I know I won't have this problem without pointers, as demo'd @ https://play.golang.org/p/ZD9JIuvdypJ.

I'd like to use pointers, as my original problem requires it. What's the correct way to achieve this?

Coming from C, this was a good problem to have! As I've learned, Go does not create a new variable for each iteration, this may get fixed in the future.

here are the two workarounds,

```
$ cat fixa.go
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
)

var (
        dests = [...]string{"word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7", "word8"}
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello!")
        fmt.Println("dests", dests)

        for i := range(dests){
                go func(dest_ptr * string){
                        fmt.Println("Handling", * dest_ptr, dest_ptr)
                }(&dests[i])

        }

        time.Sleep(200 * time.Second)
}
```

and,

```
$ cat fixb.go
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
)

var (
        dests = [...]string{"word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7", "word8"}
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello!")
        fmt.Println("dests", dests)

        for _, dest := range dests {
                dest := dest //  create a new variable, using a declaration style that may seem odd but works fine in Go: 
                go func(dest_ptr *string) {
                        fmt.Println("Trying", *dest_ptr, dest_ptr)
                }(&dest)
        }

        time.Sleep(200 * time.Second)
}
```

Comment: "this may get fixed in the future"  Unlikely: [Go 1 and the Future of Go Programs](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat)

Comment: The "workarounds" are the correct way to fix the code.

Answer (score 4):

The code in the question passes the address of the local variable `dest` to the goroutines. This local variable is set on each iteration of the loop.

Fix by passing the address of the array elements to the goroutines:

```
for i := range dests {
    fmt.Println("dest is", dests[i])
    go func(dest_ptr *string) {
        fmt.Println("Trying", *dest_ptr, dest_ptr)
    }(&dests[i])
}
```

Another approach is to create a variable on each iteration of the loop:

```
for _, dest := range dests {
    dest := dest  // <-- create new variable inside the loop
    fmt.Println("dest is", dest)
    go func(dest_ptr *string) {
        fmt.Println("Trying", *dest_ptr, dest_ptr)
    }(&dest)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> [Go: Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://golang.org/doc/faq)
>
> [What happens with closures running as goroutines?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines)
>
> each iteration of the loop uses the same instance of the variable v,
> so each closure shares that single variable.

---

For your example, for a new variable, add the `dest := dest` statement,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var (
    dests = [...]string{"word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7", "word8"}
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("dests", dests)

    for _, dest := range dests {
        dest := dest
        fmt.Println("dest is", dest)

        go func(dest_ptr *string) {
            fmt.Println("Trying", *dest_ptr, dest_ptr)
        }(&dest)

    }

    time.Sleep(200 * time.Second)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/bDI3SB1PR7X

Output:

```
dests [word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8]
dest is word1
dest is word2
dest is word3
dest is word4
dest is word5
dest is word6
dest is word7
dest is word8
Trying word1 0x40c140
Trying word2 0x40c150
Trying word3 0x40c160
Trying word4 0x40c170
Trying word5 0x40c180
Trying word6 0x40c190
Trying word7 0x40c1a0
Trying word8 0x40c1b0
```